# QML Textarea hanging with stream text

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

i using ffmpeg in my qt-python app and i redirecting the STDOUT of subprocess to a textarea in qml file , the problem is when redirects without append works fine ,but when appending text into textarea it making gui freezing with high ram usage, how to append stream text without lag, please

**main.qml**

```
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Window 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
    Window {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        visible: true
        title: qsTr("Hello World")
        Flickable  {
            id: scrollView
            x: 13
            y: 38
            width: 647
            height: 168
            contentWidth: text1.width; contentHeight: text1.height
            visible: true
            flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
            clip: true
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
            ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
            TextArea {
                id: text1
                opacity: 1
                visible: true
                color: "#000000"
                font.pixelSize: 16
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                font.preferShaping: false
                font.kerning: false
                font.styleName: "Courier New"
                font.weight: Font.Medium
                font.bold: true
                readOnly: true
                clip: true
                font.family: "Courier New"
            }
        }    
        Connections {
            target: con
            
            function onSetTx(filer){
               text1.append(filer)
               
            }
        }    
    
    }
```

**main.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import re
from threading import Thread
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QIcon
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
class Bridge(QObject):
    setTx = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        
        QObject.__init__(self)
        Thread(target=self.download).start()
    
    def download(self): 
        k = subprocess.Popen( f'"{Path(__file__).parent / "ffmpeg"}"  "Rest of arg here', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='latin-1')
        while k.poll() is None:
            std = k.stdout.readline()
            empty = re.compile('^$')
            if empty.match(std):
                pass
            else:
                self.setTx.emit(std)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    bridge = Bridge()
    context = engine.rootContext()
    context.setContextProperty("con", bridge)

    qmlFile = Path(__file__).parent / 'main.qml'
    engine.load(os.fspath(qmlFile.resolve()))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ok, *that* is a better MRE we can work with - not completely reproducible, but at least we now know how it actually works. Thanks. That said, I've to admit, I've never directly worked with QML, so I cannot give you a precise answer (yet). But others might, *now*. That said, I'd start with two questions: 1. why are you using a QObject with an underlying python thread, instead of a QThread? 2. what's the point of the regex if you're just checking if it's empty? If you're trying to adapt somebody else's code, can you point out their source so that we can have a better reference?

Comment: Most importantly, the reason for the first point is that Qt uses [thread affinity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#thread-affinity) to know where a QObject actually lives, so that it can know if the signal has to be queued (instead of *not* releasing control until the connected slot has finished its job). Right now, even if the function is threaded, the `Bridge` object still lives in the main thread. I'm not 100% sure, but that might be the reason for your issue: Qt is not able to get where the object lives, and assumes it's the same thread it was created (the main UI thread).

Comment: ok thanks, this code just produce the same problem in my original code, so the point is appending stdout making gui freezing

Comment: That is almost certainly related to the threading (UI elements are not thread safe: in certain situations they could still "work" when directly called from external threads, but that behavior is completely unreliable and trying to do it anyway is always frown upon). I'll be busy in the next few days, I'lll see if I can test and research on it later but, hopefully, somebody else with more time and experience will be able to answer you (or find an already existing answer) before that, now that you finally got a *proper* MRE ;-)

Comment: OK,Thanks for your time ,and i going to death ;-) , from morning till now no answer

Comment: Is that code example correct? I imagine you meant `text1.text.append(filer)`.

Do you need to see all the text forever as it comes in? I wonder if you're just filling up the buffers w/ how verbose FFmpeg can be. Could be worth doing something like:
`if(text1.text.length > 3000) text1.text = ""; text1.text.append(filer);` Basically just wipe out the text occasionally to make sure it doesn't get too large.

Comment: Yes correct and working ,yes forever and i will remove it when i want , i need the texarea like logging console

Comment: @Angel'sworld btw: it's "hanging", with just one "G" :-) The double consonant is usually only used for *single* consonants of the base form (if preceded by a vowel), like "blog" > "blogging" or "stop" > "stopping". (the rule is actually a bit more complex, so I suggest you to look for "present participle rules").

Comment: I’m not an English person ,so my English maybe a little bit wrong, I’m edited. And leaving the world :-)